# Exception not caught mixing contextmanager with a decorator

Tags: python, exception, decorator, contextmanager

I've been struggling for a while with this issue. In some code I'm writing I need to write a bunch of files and optionally create the directory tree if needed. My idea is as follows: catch exception IOError and if its first argument is ENOENT then create the directory structure and attempt to write the file again.

I have written a relatively small retry function but I'd like to generalize it to "any" code that might throw an exception. It all worked until I came upon something like this:

```
def retry(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print "Gotcha here!"
    return wrapper

def update(file, value):
    @contextmanager
    @retry
    def safeopen(file, mode):
        with open(file, mode) as f:
            yield f
    try:
        with safeopen(file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(value)
    except:
        print "Gotcha there!"

update( 'tests/nonexisting/dummy.txt', 'Dummy line')
```

I've tightened the code to the minimum to show what fails when `open()` throws an exception. In this code the exception is caught only from the except block in `update()`, not in `wrapper()` so I always get `Gotcha there!` although I expected `Gotcha here` instead. I've tried swapping the @decorator and @contextmanager lines, no way. I have checked and made sure the wrapper gets called: it does. Just that it catches no exception from `f()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing `@contextmanager` decorators with normal functions. The `@retry` decorator is a normal function, but you're using it to decorate a `@contextmanager` generator - this isn't going to behave the way you expect, because when you call a `@contextmanager` function, its function body isn't actually executed. Instead, a `GeneratorContextManager` object is returned. The function body isn't executed until the `__enter__` method of the `GeneratorContextManager` is called, either directly or by using a `with` statement.

Consider this example:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


def retry(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print("in wrapper")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print "Gotcha here!"
        finally:
            print "done"
    return wrapper

@contextmanager
@retry
def safeopen(file, mode):
    print("in safe open")
    with open(file, mode) as f:
        yield f

def update(file, value):
    try:
        print("CALLING SAFE OPEN")
        with safeopen(file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(value)
    except:
        print "Gotcha there!"

update( 'tests/nonexisting/dummy.txt', 'Dummy line')
```

It outputs:

```
CALLING SAFE OPEN
in wrapper
done
in safe open
Gotcha there!
```

As you can see, we exit the `retry` wrapper before we ever enter the body of `safeopen`, because `safeopen` is a context manager. It's not until the `GeneratorContextManager` object is actually returned, and evaluated as part of the `with` statement that the body is executed, but by then its too late; `retry` has exited.

To fix this, you need to make `retry` a `@contextmanager`, too, and use it to decorate the `safeopen` context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


def retry(f):
    @contextmanager
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print("in wrapper")
            with f(*args, **kwargs) as out:
                yield out
        except:
            print "Gotcha here!"
        finally:
            print "done"
    return wrapper

@retry
@contextmanager
def safeopen(file, mode):
    print("in safe open")
    with open(file, mode) as f:
        yield f

def update(file, value):
    print("CALLING SAFE OPEN")
    with safeopen(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(value)

update( 'tests/nonexisting/dummy.txt', 'Dummy line')
```

Output:

```
CALLING SAFE OPEN
in wrapper
in safe open
Gotcha here!
done
```

**Edit:**

If you reverse the ordering of the decorators, so that `retry` decorates `safeopen` directly, you can make the `retry` implementation a bit simpler, since now you're decorating a generator function, rather than a context manager:

```
def retry(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print("in wrapper")
            return next(f(*args, **kwargs))  # Call next on the generator object
        except:
            print "Gotcha here!"
        finally:
            print "done"
    return wrapper

@contextmanager
@retry
def safeopen(file, mode):
    print("in safe open")
    with open(file, mode) as f:
        yield f
```

Comment: Thank you *very* much for your detailed explanation. I indeed suspected something like this. I thought since the order of decorators matters, `retry()` only had to decorate `safeopen()` before it gets "wrapped" by the **@contextmanager** decorator. I guess Python works differently than I understood. Your example also means to me that a decorator needs to be aware of whether it acts upon a function or a generator, is that correct?

Comment: @Nasha Yes, decorators need to be aware of what kind of function they're decorating. As for the ordering of the decorators, even if you put the `retry` decorator inside of the `contextmanager` decorator, you're now decorating a generator function, rather than a context manager. The body of generator functions aren't executed when you call the function, either. You need to call `next` on the returned generator object for the body to be executed. So, what you *could* do is call `return next(f(*args, **kwargs))` inside `retry`. That might be preferable to the method I used in my answer, actually.

Comment: @Nasha I've edited my answer to show example code with the decorators reversed.

Comment: Thank you very much again for the details. It takes quite a bit of practice to understand the power of python. With your examples I now clearly see what's under the hood. I'd say what I wanted to achieve in the first place might prove too complicated, as I'd have to detect whether the decorator's argument is a function, an object, a generator, whatnot. I only have a limited set of cases to cover in my application so I better not overly complicate the code. The simplest is for `retry()` to decorate a function that doesn't yield anything.

Comment: @Nasha If you need `retry` to work decorating regular functions and generator functions, that's actually easier to do than you think, using the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isgeneratorfunction) module. `out = f(*args, **kwargs) ; if inspect.isgeneratorfunction(f): out = next(out) ; return out`